# How to remove ^M characters from file in aix?

Tags: unix, aix

I have tried following commands, but they don't work. `sed` isn't installed and hence doesn't work. Same goes for `dos2unix`.

```
awk 'sub(/^M/,"")' finename

cat finename | sed 's/^M//’ > finename

awk '{sub(/^M/,"")}1' finename > finename

tr -d $'\r' < finename

tr -d '\015' < finename > finename

awk 'sub(/^M/,"");1' finename
```

Comment: Please check again: `sed` is installed. Nonetheless bash-ism like $'\r' don't work in Korn shell.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked :
tr -d '\r' < filename > new_file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is the `dos2unix` way. In case it's not installed, you might try this:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

In case the installation of `dos2unix` is not permitted, you might try the following command:

```
sed 's/\r//' input > output
```

If `sed` is not working too, you might go for the following `awk` solution:

```
awk '{sub(/^M/,"")}1' input > output
```

(Afterwards you just rename `output` back to `input`)

Comment: I can't install, it's not permitted. That's why looking for a command ( not manually)

Comment: @Shivani: I've adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: awk '{sub(/^M/,"")}1' input > output  - doesn't wok :(

Comment: @Dominique : `sub(/^M/, "")` removes a literal `ASCII` `"M"` at start of line. i'm guessing OP wanna remove either `\r` or literal combo `"^M"` (if the file already had been pre-mangled) - maybe something like `sub(/(\r|[\^]M)$/, "")` instead ?

Comment: `apt install` is a non-starter on AIX

Answer (score 0):

if the file hasn't been pre-mangled by `cat` into caret notation of `"^M"` for `\r`, one could try

> ```
> {m,n,g}awk 3 ORS= RS='\r'
> ```

if it has already been mangled,

> ```
> gawk -Pe/-ce NF=NF OFS= FS='[\\^]M' # these 2 gawk modes act up; 
>                                     # switching to FS instead of RS
> gawk/nawk    6     ORS= RS='\\^M' 
> mawk         9     ORS= RS='\^M'
> ```